# Speed of HTTP GET Method in C++

Tags: c++, http, sockets, get

I have been using certain libraries in a C++ program to connect and fetch different websites. Mainly I used Chillkat and Curl. However, recently I started programming my own HTTP fetcher, using the help of MSDN and the Winsocket2 library.

I programmed my software to open a socket with SOCKET_STREAM type and for Ipv4, 
and then I establish a connection with the required website, and send a GET request with "Host:" and "Connection: close" headers to the server. 
Everything seems to work fine, However, the performance is not as I expected. The bundled Chillkat library still preforms better then mine. Even though I have optimized mine as much as I can.

I notice that when I send the request, some servers take longer time to respond. And once they do they send everything at once chunked. So how can I make a header-request that initiates a fast response? Speed matters a lot for my program.

Comment: I doubt there's a header that requests a speed-bump, though you can check the headers that Chillkat sends to make sure you aren't missing anything. As for chunking, that's normal; a lot of sites do that, so you'll have to handle that in your own library.

Comment: Check if changing socket buffer will give you a boost, maybe you waste your time for reading to often small chunks of data. Sometimes it's better to wait for bigger chunk and pass it at once, instead of reading many times small chunks

Comment: The chances of a single individual writing an optimized function that beats the optimizations performed by a group of thousands of combined developers all code reviewing and critiquing each others optimizations are small to practically zero. If speed matters use a well established library that is in common usage and know for its speed.

Comment: I'm kind of realizing that by experience,I would like to use Chillkat as I find if very optimized , however, it is not open source. And for cURL it is written in C and I'm using C++ , hence , when I use the wrapper version , I have so many errors compiling it!! I'm not an expert C++ programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing performance differences on a modern machine with low volumes, the most likely problem is that you have forgotten to turn off the Nagle algorithm. Use setsockopt() to set TCP_NODELAY to 1. HTTP is not Telnet.

I wouldn't worry about explicit flushing or buffer management or anything like that until you see a performance problem and you have enough volume to notice. Other than writing your request in a single write call.

For download speed, window size makes a difference. You can tune SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF. Bear in mind that the values that make your benchmarks go fast might make your real-world performance slow.

Comment: Thanks janm, I turned the Nagle algo off and it doubled my speed, it was really helpful..now I have a speed equivalent if not faster than the Chillkat library..

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, HTTP is a complex standard, and there are many ways to optimize an implementation. However, the chances of your having enough time to optimize it better than an already packaged library such as Chillkat or Curl is highly unlikely. If you did want to go about it, I would suggest reducing the number of headers you send, and flushing the socket buffer (bypassing Nagle's algorithm) after writing the status line to the socket. This will give a properly coded server slightly longer (several ms tops) to respond to your request. But even that may blow up in your face if your network configuration is not "ideal".

Finally, keep in mind that when it comes to networks, there is a very large margin of error, and you may get different results using different tactics with different servers, networks, and even OSs.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I would love to use cURL, but I have no idea how to compile it for C++, MVC++ 2010.

Comment: cURL can't NOT have a package for M$ development.  Check the downloads page (http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).